# how to call new program everytime using process.start

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a URL that launches Excel through a .net program. I use process.start(excel.exe, param) and it works fine if there are no excel opened in the target machine.

For example. if there is no excel opened in the desktop, when user click on the url, I see excel open up and process params correctly.

If there is already an excel open and when user click on the url, the process.start call doesn't work, meaning, the params are not getting process because the application has already loaded the addin.

My question is, how can I make the process.start launch a new session of Excel instead of using an existing session.

Thanks

Refeekh

Comment: I think something like notepad with open a new instance (?), does it have to be excel?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried notepad and process.start launch new instance of notepad for every process.start call.

Answer (score 0):

call `process.destroy();` after starting process this would kill process every time so when ever you call that process a fresh process will be initiated .